# Import custom tagLib without the use of directives like <%@

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, taglib, scriptlet

I have disabled scriptlet in all my JSPs in web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

But I need to import some custom tagLibs which are being used like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="/tags-utils" %>
```

How do I import that without using scriptlet?
Also, how do I avoid using the following?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

The decision of scriptlet removal is to avoid the scriptlet mess in a project written by more than one developer.

If it is not possible to change the import without using scriptlet then how I would disable it for any use other than `<%@ taglib` or  `<%@ page`?

Tried to change from

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

to

```
<jsp:directive.tagLib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags" />
```

but Servlet throws me an error:

> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/portal].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-80-3) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(2,18) <jsp:directive.tag directive can only be used in a tag file

Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JSP 2.2 Spec**

**JSP 1.3.10.1 EBNF Grammar for JSP Syntax**

```
ScriptlessBody ::= ( ( ‘<%--’ JSPCommentBody )
                   | ( ‘<%@’ DirectiveBody )
                   | ( ‘<jsp:directive.’ XMLDirectiveBody )
                   | ( ‘<%!’ <TRANSLATION_ERROR> )
                   | ( ‘<jsp:declaration’ <TRANSLATION_ERROR> )
                   | ( ‘<%=’ <TRANSLATION_ERROR> )
                   | ( ‘<jsp:expression’ <TRANSLATION_ERROR> )
                   | ( ‘<%’ <TRANSLATION_ERROR> )
                   | ( ‘<jsp:scriptlet’ <TRANSLATION_ERROR> )
                   | ( ‘${‘ ELExpressionBody )
                   | ( ‘#{‘ ELExpressionBody )
                   | ( ‘<jsp:text’ XMLTemplateText )
                   | ( ‘<jsp:’ StandardAction )
                   ( ( ‘</’ ExtraClosingTag )
                   | ( ‘<‘ CustomAction CustomActionBody )
                   | TemplateText
                   )*
```

---

So, when `scripting-invalid=true`:

**Illegal**

```
<%
<%!
<%=
<jsp:scriptlet
<jsp:declaration
<jsp:expression
```

**Legal**

```
<%@
<jsp:directive.
<jsp:
```

**The following is legal:**

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="/tags-utils" %>
```

**As long as the "app context uri" + "/tags-utils" (the taglib's context-relative path) maps to "taglib absolute uri".**

**Alternatively, you can try:**

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="http://www.mycorp/utiltags" %>  // use your absolute taglib URI
```

OR

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="utils" uri="uri_path_relative_to_jsp_uri" %>  // no leading "/"
```

OR

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="utils" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %> // include subdir if approp
```

**The following is invented.  There's no `jsp:directive.tagLib` tag defined.  Don't use.**

```
 <jsp:directive.tagLib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags" />
```

**Instead of:**

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

**Try:**

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>  // language is for scriptlets
```

Answer (score -1):

`<%@taglib` and `<%@page` are directives, not scriptlets.

Scriptlets would have `<%`.

Alternatively you can write like this

```
<jsp:directive.taglib uri="uri" prefix="prefixOfTag" />
```

Comment: "<jsp:directive.tag directive can only be used in a tag file". Even using <%@ it is considered script by <scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>

Comment: @FagnerBrack, no, you're wrong. There are two ways of declaring any jsp elements one is old <%... style and another is <jsp: prefix new style

Comment: When I use this directive using the tag it does not autocomplete on eclipse and throws the error: "(http-localhost-127.0.0.1-80-5) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(2,18) <jsp:directive.tag directive can only be used in a tag file"

Comment: I have updated in the question the exact change I've made. I am using eclipse and it does not autocomplete the <jsp:directive tag, is there any configuration I need to make to get this working?